Angular: Await method do not execute the route.navigate() present inside the setTimeout?
I faced a weird issue when I am integrating a async routing above the await method. If I remove the await method, I can see the routing id working as expected. Below I am giving the code sample.
async deleteApplication() {
        const confirm = await this._prompt.showDelteConfirm(this.application.name);
        if (confirm) {
            // Block 1 start
            setTimeout(async () => {
                try {
                    await this._router.navigate(['/tenant']);
                    console.log('redirected.');
                } catch (error) {
                    console.error('Error navigating within tenant:', error);
                }
            }, 5000);
            // Block 1 end

            // BLock 2 start
            const {result} = await this._applicationService.delete();
            if (result === 'Success') {
                await this._projectSpaces.request();
                await this._router.navigate(['/tenant']);
            }
            // BLock 2 end
        }
    }

I suppose to redirect to a new route after few seconds (i.e after 5sec) as soon as after the delete() service started.
If block 1 and Block 2 execute at a time, When await methods start executing then the routing method present inside the block 1 is not executing.
Don't understand this kind of weird issue.
I need your thought on this.

what's the point of this._router.navigate(['/tenant']); in a timeout AND conditionally based on the result of this._applicationService.delete(); - seems you only need lines 1, 2, 3, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 22 and 23 ... with 19 and 20 swapped position

@jarmanda I think the requirement is we need to redirect to tenant page and call the delete api in the backend. Can we achieve this ? We just need to call the api and then redirect back to tenant page. No need to wait for api response to be completed?

Asker is not reacting to comments. Voting to close.
